# Transfer function of an ideal op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

This problem requires solving for V2/V1.
My approach: R2 and R4 parallel reason: R2 has virtual ground and  R4 is connected to the ground.
 Applied Nodal Analysis and got the following answer(incorrect).
[image]
The correct answer should be:
[image]
How should I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably thought:

The current flowing from V1 towards the opamp equals the current from the opamp's negative input terminal towards the output, so:

$$  \frac{V_1}{R_1} = - \frac{V_2}{R_3 + \frac{R_2 R_4}{R_2+R_4} } $$

But the current flowing from V1 towards the opamp flows through R2 and is then **divided** to a current to ground (through R4) and a current to the output V2 (through R3).

So, first apply KCL, defining \$i_x\$ as the current through \$R_x\$

$$ i_1 = i_2 \text{ }\text{ and }\text{ } i_4 = i_2 + i_3 $$

and (like Andy aka suggested) define a node Vx at the junction of R2, R3 and R4, then:

$$ i_1 = \frac{V_1}{R_1} $$

$$ i_2 = -\frac{V_x}{R_2} $$

$$ i_4 = \frac{V_x}{R_4} $$

$$ i_3 = \frac{V_2-V_x}{R_3} $$

and solve this.

Spoiler solution below:

> \begin{align} \text{Using }\text{ } i 4 =i 2 +i 3 \\ \\ \frac{V_x}{R_4} = -\frac{V_x}{R_2} +  \frac{V_2}{R_3} -  \frac{V_x}{R_3} \\  \\ \text{Substituting }\text{ } i_1=i_2 \rightarrow V_x=-\frac{V_1 R_2}{R_1} \\ \\ - \frac{V_1 R_2}{R_1 R_4} =\frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_2}{R_3} + \frac{V_1 R_2}{R_1 R_3} \\  \\ - \frac{V_1 R_2}{R_1 R_4} - \frac{V_1}{R_1} - \frac{V_1 R_2}{R_1 R_3} = \frac{V_2}{R_3} \\ \\ - \frac{R_2 R_3}{R_1 R_4} - \frac{R_3}{R_1} - \frac{R_2}{R_1} = \frac{V_2}{V_1} \\ \\ \frac{V_2}{V_1} = - \frac{R_2 R_3}{R_1 R_4} - \frac{R_3 R_4}{R_1 R_4} - \frac{R_2 R_4}{R_1 R_4} \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You should calculate the formula for voltage (Vx) at the junction of R2, R3 and R4 based on R4 and R2 being parallel then, the op-amp circuit gain equation becomes Vx/V1 = -R2/R1.

Finally, using the first formula I mentioned (that you need to calculate), substitute for Vx in the latter equation.